# Error popping up while setting on click listner in spinners

Tags: java, android, xml, onclick, spinner

#### Im new to android and searched a lot regarding this problem but couldnt find solution,im getting this error while setting on click listner option on the spinner options,please help me in solving this error though its a small one.

## Error

### The method setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) in the type AdapterView is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity)

```
 #MainActivity.java
 package com.example.spinners;

 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;


  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
 // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
         R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 // Apply the adapter to the spinner
 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
 ;

}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
    // code 
}
}
```

## activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.spinners.MainActivity" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The method setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) in the type AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter> is not 
 applicable for the arguments (MainActivity)

Comment: The error is coming for this line :-spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

This expects `this` to be an object that implements the onItemSelectedListener interface, you can do it as you want, but you need to change this

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements onItemSelectedListener
```

and implement the method

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
    // code 
}
```

Edit:

and this method

```
@Override
public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: I did that but another error is coming now -onItemSelectedListner cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Use `import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`

Comment: plz have a look at my MainActivity.java code i have made the required changes but still one error is coming i.e The type MainActivity must implement the inherited abstract method 
 AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>)

Comment: this error is coming on this line-:public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

Comment: Pretty straightforward; just implement that method that it's complaining about

Comment: You dont have to do anything in the function, just add it to your code

Comment: The errors got removed but when I'm running the app their is nothing showing up when i select the items from the drop down menu

Comment: That is out of the scope of this question. We don't even know what you're trying to achieve. You might want to ask a new question for that

Comment: My sole purpose is to display the particular option on the screen as soon as a option is selected that is what onclick listner is used for,but here it is not displaying the options